# DRAM instrumentation

Tags: memory, x86, performance-testing

I am trying to monitor the physical DRAM. Specifically, I am trying to find out the humber of reads and writes performed on the physical DRAM so that I can have a rough estimate of what the total memory energy consumption is when running a specific application. Do you know about any tools that would help with this measurements?

Comment: Please give more details of the hardware.  There is no way to do this generically.  Is this ARM, PowerPC, x86?  Do you have specific device, like an *iPhone*, an IBM AIX Server?

Comment: it is an X86 machine. I basically want to know the number of reads and writes to the physical memory, or maybe dump the contents of the physical memory in a file periodically and write a software that parses these snapshots and give me the information I want

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization